# Cordova version in use in a multi device hybrid app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How can I see the cordova version that is in use in a visual studio multi device hybrid app application?

Answer (score 0):

The value is stored in the JavaScript global `cordova.version`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Cordova and Cordova-CLI version by looking into following files:

1.) Cordova version = bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\version
[image]

2.) Cordova CLI version = bld\Debug\platforms\cli-version

[image]

Comment: How can I update my CTP2 project to CTP3 and forces it to use cordova 4 (4 is the version that comes with CTP3)??

Comment: You need to install CPT3 from here http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/dn841948#Fragment_Quickstart. Open the project after installing CPT3.0, you might have to remove and add plugins and build the project, it should use Cordova-CLI4.0